# Coding ranges in Stata

Tags: stata

I was given a dataset that is VERY crude. One dataset gives me a code for each X variable (a 4 digit code) and then a text file that explains what each code means. Weirdly a code can mean something or a range could mean the same thing. For example:

```
X
2321
2322
2341
2520
2572
4000
4001
4002
4100
```

The text file is this way:

```
2300-2372 = New York
2520      = Chicago
2572      = Denver
4000-4099 = Austin
4100-4200 = San Diego
```

I wanted an easy way to code the Stata file given without creating 100's of lines of codes. Since I have over 1000 classifications and about one million observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inrange`:

```
gen austin = 0
replace austin = 1 if inrange(X, 4000,4099)
```

For the, here cities, that have one code then make the range start and stop at the same point

Comment: `gen austin = inrange(X, 4000,4099)` gets you there in one. But do you really want a separate variable for each place?

Comment: See also the concurrent thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591130/in-stata-how-do-i-add-variable-labels-from-a-separate-csv-file for the idea of converting a text file into a do file.